# Write_csv for a list of csv.files mantaining original file names

Tags: r, list, csv

I have a df list (df_list) and i want a tydiverse approach to write all csv files from my list while mantaining their original file names.

So far i did:

```
df = dir(pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)  
df_list = vector("list",length(df))
  
for(i in seq_along(networks)) 
{   
  df_list[[i]] = read.csv(df[[i]], sep = ";") 

}
```

`imap(df_list, ~write_csv(.x, paste0(.y,".csv")))`

my current output is:

```
1.csv; 2.csv; 3.csv ...
```

Comment: Your code will work fine as long as the names of the df_list are the original filenames. But from your output it looks as if your list has no names.

Comment: I think that is the problem i am currently constructing the df_list as follows:

`networks = dir(pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

network_list = vector("list",length(networks))

for(i in seq_along(networks))
{
  network_list[[i]] = read.csv(networks[[i]], sep = ";")
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will read in a set of files from an example directory, apply a function to those files, then save the files with the exact same names.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

# Create example directory with example .csv files
dir.create(path = "example")
data.frame(x1 = letters) %>% write.csv(., file = "example/example1.csv")
data.frame(x2 = 1:20) %>% write.csv(., file = "example/example2.csv")

# Get relative paths of all .csv files in the example subdirectory
path_list <- list.files(pattern = "example.*csv", recursive = TRUE) %>%
  as.list()

# Read every file into list
file_list <- path_list %>%
  map(~ read.csv(.x, sep = ","))

# Do something to the data
file_list_updated <- file_list %>%
  map( ~ .x %>% mutate(foo = 5))

# Write the updated files to the old file names
map2(.x = file_list_updated,
     .y = path_list,
     ~ write.csv(x = .x, file = .y))
```

Comment: It was really a reading problem. Thanks!